# Can I disable type errors from third-party packages in Pylance?

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing, pylance

Some of the packages I use don't type hint their code, so when I use them, Pylance keeps telling me that the functions I use have partially unknown types, which is a problem I can't fix. Is there a way to disable such errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're absolutely certain of the type you're getting from the external library and you're sure it's not documented through [typeshed](https://github.com/python/typeshed) either, you can always [`cast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.cast) it to signal to the type checker it's to be treated as that type.

```py
from typing import cast
from elsewhere import Ham

spam = some_untyped_return()
ham = cast(Ham, spam)
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
# type: ignore
```

Place this comment at the top of a file to ignore all type-checking errors in the file.

Similarly, place it at the end of a line to just ignore errors on that line.

When I come across a third-party package that doesn't provide typing information, I generally make a wrapper for it, in a file on its own, and use that wrapper from the rest of my codebase - this allows me to just use the per-file ignore, while minimising the amount of code that has to have type-checking disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the severity level for [pyright's diagnostics rules](https://microsoft.github.io/pyright/#/configuration?id=diagnostic-rule-defaults) in your `settings.json` like this:

```json
    "python.analysis.diagnosticSeverityOverrides": {
        "reportUnknownVariableType": "none"
    },
```

You can also configure it for your project using the `pyproject.toml` tool table:

```ini
[tool.pyright]
reportUnknownVariableType = false
```

Comment: But I think that will also hide the `reportUnknownVariableType` error when I forgot to add the type annotation in my own code, right?